# jquery adding duplicate element

Tags: jquery

I am working on some ajax pagination. I am using the below code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('#content').on('click', '.woocommerce-pagination a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).load(link + ' #content', function() {

            $(this).fadeIn(200);
            $('.products li').css("width","21.05%");
            $('#content').css("width","70%");
        });
    });
});
});
```

This works as it should, but for some reason it is adding #content within the original #content div. When i view source it looks like this:

```
<div id="content" role="main" style="display: block; width: 70%;">
<div id="content" role="main">
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone see what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wrapper, better to use reference variables to this are my thumb rules to avoid such mistakes that could really kill your time if it's get in your head....

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).load(link + ' #content'...
```

You say load whatever is inside `http://...... #content` into the `#content` on the site I'm on. You could add a wrapper that holds the content to avoid such a behavior.

Answer (score 1):

i think here is the problem

```
$(this).load(link + ' #content', function() {
```

i think you are loading **#content** from link in **#content** in your page

this means second #content is loaded from link an you should load its content